# Troubleshooting jQuery-UI Autocomplete with Remote Datasource

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to get the jQuery UI AutoComplete widget working with a remote data source in a WebForms application. I have it successfully calling my web service, but the control does not pop up the list with the returned items.

Here's my markup:

```
<p>
    <label for="birds" class="fieldLabel">Company:</label>
    <input id="existingProgramCompanyName" type="text" style="width: 350px" />
</p>
```

And here's my script:

```
$("#existingProgramCompanyName").autocomplete({
    source: "/Services/ProgramListServices.asmx/FilteredProgramList",
    minLength: 3,
    select: function (event, ui) {
        alert('Got it!');
    }
});
```

Whenever I've done this in the past, my biggest problem has been returning the data in the right format. The AutoComplete widget wants JSON and so I've spent considerable time getting my code to return valid JSON. Here's the actual string being returned from my web service:

```
{
  "Companies":[{"Id":"1","Value":"First","Label":"First"},
               {"Id":"2","Value":"Second","Label":"Second"},
               {"Id":"3","Value":"Third","Label":"Third"}],
  "HasData":true,"Message":"","Success":true
}
```

Is that valid JSON?

The control correctly shows the little animated loading image. My web service is being called and is returning without error. But the AutoComplete control never pops up the list.

Does anyone see any problems with what I have so far? And what would be the next step in trying to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Yes it is a valid JSON Object (a parsed json).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your string is valid JSON, but it doesn't mean that AutoComplete can consume it. Formats can be seen at [Autocomplete Widget Source](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source). I think specifically this applies to your case for source:

```
* An array of strings: [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
* An array of objects with label and value properties: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
```

What your feed is generating will not work as expected, whether you surround it in brackets or not (you'll need the brackets):

```
$("#existingProgramCompanyName").autocomplete({
    source: {"Companies": [{ "Id": "1", "Value": "First", "Label": "First" },
        { "Id": "2", "Value": "Second", "Label": "Second" },
        { "Id": "3", "Value": "Third", "Label": "Third"}],
        "HasData": true, "Message": "", "Success": true
        }
    });
```

However, this slightly modified version will (note the cases are lowercase):

```
 $("#existingProgramCompanyName").autocomplete({
     source: [{ "value": "First", "label": "First" },
              { "value": "Second", "label": "Second" },
              { "value": "Third", "label": "Third"}]
     });
```

So, to fix, I would tweak your JSON feed to output a different format!

**Update**: perhaps just try the array of strings option for testing:

```
List<string> s = new List<string>();
//populate the list
return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(s);
```

Comment: I think we are talking about different things here. If `source` is set to a string value, the string represents a URL, as demonstrated in my markup code. I am talking about the JSON returned from the web service that the AutoComplete code is calling.

Comment: Yes I understand that... but if it can't parse it as a JSON object as shown above, why would it be able to parse that same JSON object fed from your URL.

Comment: Well, that's what I'm trying to work through. I was thrown by your syntax. Perhaps you are just showing what the format needs to be?

Comment: Yes, sorry! I was just showing that as an example, and meaning change your JSON out from Example 1 (what your feed currently generates) to what I show in Example 2 (a slightly modified version of your JSON feed).

Comment: And, by the way, my web service creates an instance of a class that derives from JsonResponse, and then calls .Serialize() on that instance. So, unfortunately, I don't have much control over the additional data.

Comment: Or perhaps change it to a simple array of strings if you can.

Comment: <sigh>, I think I'm in a little over my head here. To call the `Serialize()` method, it must derive from JsonResponse. So I don't know how to make it a simple string array. And, also, if I don't add the `Success` value, how does it know if there was an error?

Comment: I will start a new, modified question.

Comment: @JonathanWood I added a example of creating string array. As for the erroring... IDK. I didn't see anything on error like what `$.ajax` has.

Comment: Interesting. I'll check that out. Didn't know there was a static version of `Serialize()`. Thanks!